# Is the conditional tense commonly used in new reporting?

Tags: temps-grammatical, conditionnel

I notice a lot of online blog articles which use conditional tense to express some report:

> En effet, Apple **aurait** déjà commencé à discuter avec des potentiels partenaires d’une extension d’Apple Pay sur le web.

I am translating this as

> Apple already started discussion with potential partners to extend Apple Pay for the web.

I find it unusual in English at least, to say

> Apple would have already started discussion with ....

On top of the title question, does anyone know a good article that explains this use of the tense?

Comment: If the body of your post matched with the title it would be a slightly different question than the one I marked it as a duplicate of. If frequency was put forward as the main topic we could maybe keep the question separate.

Comment: In that case, I think it is a duplicate. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

That tense used to express precautions regarding to the sentence is indeed commonly used in journalism.

"According to our sources, it might be eventually be plausible that xxx. But nothing is certain so take this information with a grain of salt"

This allows the journalist to report news without being accused of false information afterwards if this reveals false.

However they can also use a formula a bit less cautious : "Selon nos informations" + passé composé

> Selon nos informations, un accident a eu lieu sur l'A6